# if_else not working as expected inside dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, rstudio

You can copy the following code to an `R` script file and run it:

```
preprocess_brand_version = function(dataset) {
  dataset$brand_version = gsub("^([0-9]+)(\\.[0-9]+)?.*$", "\\1\\2", dataset$brand_version, perl = TRUE)
  dataset = dataset %>% mutate(
    brand_version = ifelse(!(is.na(brand) || is.na(brand_version)), paste(substr(brand, 1, 3), ", ", brand_version, sep = ""), NA)
  )
  dataset$brand_version = as.factor(dataset$brand_version)
  return (dataset)
}

a = data.frame(brand = c("Samsung", "Motorola"), brand_version = c("1.4.3", "6.3"))
b = a
b[1,2] = NA
a
b
preprocess_brand_version(b)
```

**My problem** is that when I run that, I get:

```
> a
     brand brand_version
1  Samsung         1.4.3
2 Motorola           6.3

> b
     brand brand_version
1  Samsung          <NA>
2 Motorola           6.3

> preprocess_brand_version(b)
     brand brand_version
1  Samsung          <NA>
2 Motorola          <NA>
```

I was expecting to get: "Mot, 6.3" as the new value for the version on Motorola row.

Any idea why the: `if_else` is not working as I would expect?

Thanks!

Comment: In your code you're using `ifelse` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one vertical bar for the or:

```
preprocess_brand_version = function(dataset) {
  dataset$brand_version = gsub("^([0-9]+)(\\.[0-9]+)?.*$", "\\1\\2", dataset$brand_version, perl = TRUE)
  dataset = dataset %>% mutate(
    brand_version = ifelse(!(is.na(brand) | is.na(brand_version)), paste(substr(brand, 1, 3), ", ", brand_version, sep = ""), NA)
  )
  dataset$brand_version = as.factor(dataset$brand_version)
  return (dataset)
}
```

if you want I have a short tutorial on youtube about regular expressions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeMC1aNNu-4

Answer (score 1):

You're using the double form 'or' `||` which is forcing the code to go through each element in your pattern. Switching to the short form `|` should solve this.